# removing number from notification icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a notification icon that has the number of notifications as below. I'm trying to remove the number upon clicking on the icon.

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>Notifications <span class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
```

Which is the easiest way to do it, Jquery, or there is an easier way in HTML ?

Comment: JQuery would be easier in my opinion. If you could post more of your code within a jsfiddle or another tool, I could show you how to do so in JQuery.

Comment: `{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}` so what is the framework, seems like it would be better to use the framework. Or is that serverside code? But you can add a click handler.... `onclick="this.textContent=''"`

Comment: could you specify more code, that is associated with the page, where this notification is being displayed to show more workflow, so we can understand better.. but JQuery can work, we just want to know how to implement it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the span on click.

```js
$(".glyphicon").on("click",function(){ $(".badge").remove(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click on ICON below to remove the number </h2>
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe">(ICON) </span>Notifications <span class="badge">10</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a JS that had an EventListener for every time you click the button, the number resets to 0. 
Something similar to this:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.notification');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var count = Number(el.getAttribute('data-count')) || 0;
    el.setAttribute('data-count', count);
    el.classList.remove('notify');
    el.offsetWidth = el.offsetWidth;
    el.classList.add('notify');
    if(count === 0){
        el.classList.add('show-count');
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an onclick in the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeNumber()">
```

Then create a JS function that removes that number:

```
function removeNumber() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('badge')[0].innerHTML = '';
}
```

Or if you want to hide the full `badge`

```
function removeNumber() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('badge')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

I would suggest to avoid using JQuery for that kind of things which can be achieved easily with JS.